# How to get substring in panda data frame when certain characters exist in the row?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, substring

I have a data frame where certain rows contains a special character '#'.

Here's my data and I can find the index positions of '#' :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=['fig#abc', 'strawberry', 'applepie#efg'], columns=['fruitname'])
ind= df.fruitname.str.find("#")
df['col1'].str.find(".")-1]
print df
print ind


    fruitname
0   fig#abc
1   strawberry
2   applepie#efg

0    3
1   -1
2    8
```

I want to have a  new column data with value of the first few characters before '#' if the index '#' is greater then 4, otherwise with value of the original data  as:

```
   fruitname_new
0  fig#abc
1  strawberry
2  applepie
```

What is the best way to get this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#use apply to split fruitname and then check the length before setting the new fruitname column.

df['fruitname_new'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.fruitname if len(x.fruitname.split('#')[0])<=4 else x.fruitname.split('#')[0], axis=1)

df
Out[484]: 
      fruitname fruitname_new
0       fig#abc       fig#abc
1    strawberry    strawberry
2  applepie#efg      applepie
```